# Sharing tensorflow model between processes

Tags: tensorflow, ipc

I have several processes running on a server, one of which is training a model in tensorflow. Periodically, I want the trainer to send the current model to the other processes. The way I do this now is with the usual `Saver` class that can `save` to and `restore` from disk.

However, I think this form of IPC is rather inefficient, and it is potentially causing filesystem lockups on the server. If there were a way to serialize the variables into some blob I could send that over a zmq broadcast pipe, I but I haven't found this in the docs.

Alternatively, distributed tensorflow is probably up to the task, but I don't think I need something so complicated.

Comment: what about using /tmpfs to save to RAM instead of disk?

Comment: Unfortunately that won't work since the jobs are spread out over several different nodes which don't share RAM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could preshare the architecture then use  `tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.VARIABLES)` at every number of steps of your liking, and run it to get the values, then you can use `variable.assign` at the other end to load up the values in the appropriate variables.

Comment: Would this be guaranteed to give me the variables in the same order on both sides?

Comment: get_collection returns the tensor object and you can just fetch their name. you'll have to use `your_session.run(the_tensor_list)` to get the associated values, which will be in the same order you put the tensors in the_tensor_list. you can then serialize everything as needed, in protobuf or whatever